# laravel union query to get data per hour of the day and show 0 if there is no data

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this mysql query that I am trying to translate into laravel query builder can anyone please help?

```
SELECT   CONCAT(HOUR, ':00-', HOUR+1, ':00') AS Hours,
     COUNT(o.id) AS id_count  
FROM  (  SELECT 0 AS HOUR
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23) AS AllHours
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON HOUR(created_at) = HOUR AND o.created_at = '2019-10-10'
GROUP BY HOUR
ORDER BY HOUR;
```

Cheers

Cam

Comment: why must be translated into laravel query builder? why not create RAW query?

Comment: I just thought that would be the most effective way of doing it.